# std::make_pair <const char*,int >

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function which was called from the of 'main' method with the same arguments that main was called with  `(int main (int argc, char* argv[]))`

```
std::pair<const char *, int> mtd1 (int argc, char * argv[]){
.
.
.
}
```

since  argv[1]  is a pointer to a String (assume that it was atleast one program argument except for argv[0]), but not a constant pointer, is it still possible (not an error) to pass argv[1] in a return statement  inside `mtd1`

```
return std::make_pair <argv[1],99999 >
```

or do i need to do this inside my `mtd1` method

```
const char *abc  = arg[1]
```

before returning

```
return std::make_pair (abc,99999 )      <- edited
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling it?

Comment: Whether it is possible (safe) will depend on what is passed to `mtd1`. By the way, what is `String`?

Comment: You probably meant `std::make_pair` with the regular, not angular, brackets.

Comment: `std::make_pair <argv[1],99999 >` [didn't compile](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yMX8YZtW8pENVScS). Do you mean `std::make_pair (argv[1],99999 )`?

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it the safe way?

```
std::pair<std::string, int> mtd1 (int argc, char * argv[])
{
.
.
.
}
```

and

```
return std::make_pair (std::string(argv[1]),99999);
```

If you insist on returning `std::pair<char*,int>`, then this should work:

```
return std::make_pair (argv[1],99999);
```

Comment: how could you map `string` with `integer` `pair<std::string, int> mtd1 (int argc, char * argv[])`

Comment: @someone There was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist   the method shall return a std::pair<const char *, int>

Comment: @J.doe While I don't see why that's necessary, I'll add that to my code too.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist sorry I am just learning c++ Iam just a bit confused about things so i might ask silly questions ...

Comment: @J.doe For a beginner, I don't recommend using `char*` in an `std::pair` (even for an expert, but a beginner is easily confused with that). If that works for you, then great. But remember that the `std::pair<char*,int>` doesn't have your string, but has a *pointer* to your string, meaning that you have to be aware of all memory management stuff. And don't worry about being a beginner. We all were beginners once.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist , but argv[1] is not of type: const char*  ,so why is it possible? argv[1] is: char * right?

Comment: @j.doe casting char* to const char* is no problem. The other way around can be a problem and needs a special kind of cast operator.